# C++ File Reading while loop runs to infinite

Tags: c++, file-io

I am trying to read from a file using a while loop and I am stuck as to why it keeps looping forever. I think it has something to do with my while loop condition but I am unable to figure it out.

```
#include <iostream>
    #include <fstream>
    #include <cstdlib>
    
    using namespace std;
    
    int main()
    {
        string name;
        int age, favNum;
        
        ifstream inFile;
        inFile.open("Trial.txt");
        if(inFile.fail())
        {
            cout << "No Such File!" << endl;
            exit(100);
        }
        
        cout << "The names are: " << endl;
        while(!inFile.eof())
        {
            getline(inFile, name);
            cout << name << endl;
            
            inFile >> age;
            cout << age << endl;
            
            inFile >> favNum;
            cout << favNum << endl;
            
            inFile.ignore(100, '\n');
        }
        
        inFile.close();
    }
```

Text File

```
Joe
10 12
Zoe
20 12
John
19 12
Harold
20 12
```

Comment: It doesn't `keeps looping forever` in my computer, are you sure about that?

Comment: Yeah for some reason in my laptop it keeps looping forever

Comment: I tried it on my friends laptop and it does not loop forever on his too, could something be wrong with my laptop?

Comment: Try clean all the binaries and recompile your program.

Comment: [why-is-iostreameof-inside-a-loop-condition-i-e-while-stream-eof-cons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605125/why-is-iostreameof-inside-a-loop-condition-i-e-while-stream-eof-cons)

Comment: In other words, try using `while(getline(inFile, name) && inFile >> name >> age) {...}`

Answer (score 0):

Correct way of reading from file  is as follows:

While(infile>>name)
Cout <<name<<endl;

Using !inFile.eof as condition is problematic.